# Calling a method using strings

Tags: javascript

I have an object like so:

```
var x = {
    "fx": function() {...}
}
```

I have the name of the object (`y = "x"`) and the function (`z = "fx"`) and have them as strings.

I know I can call the function through the use of eval through the following method or similar:

```
eval(y.z)
```

However, I would like to avoid using eval to accomplish this. I know the `apply` prototype method takes a function and applies it to an object, however searching for the function reference is impossible as the function is contained within the object.

I know this problem is not a new one and hence must have a solution, but I cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you are assigning `y = "x"`? You can use `x[z]()`, `eval` is bad and should be avoided

Comment: I'm just using that to represent that the object name is a string; I am not using eval in any way or form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 x[y]()
```

to call the function with a variable

Comment: This is correct, thank you. I'd like to note for future readers that the object can be obtained by using `window[x]`.

Comment: @Saikyr only if the object is defined in the global scope

Comment: That is correct, guess you'd have to chain references from the global scope to the correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

What I've understood is that y and z are some variables and you want to call z method of y object using these variables.

It can be accomplished by various ways. For instance:

```
(function () {
x = {
    "fx": function () {
        alert("Hey!");
    }
}
    y = "x";
    z = "fx";
    this[y][z]();
}());
```

[DemoFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xqkbszg/)